# A strange proper name

Tags: proper-nouns

Why the complete name of British philosopher McTaggart, i.e. **John McTaggart Ellis McTaggart**, has such an strange form?

Edit: Considering @Lawrence concerns, I should note that, although *strangeness* is a somehow subjective matter, but it's objectively based on the lack of similar cases. In this case, I have never seen a compound proper name with a repeated part. I guess the two *McTaggart*s refer to two different persons (ex., the philosopher and his father). This theory may be confirmed/rejected by historical notes; or at least by providing more examples, one may reduce its degree of *strangeness* to non natives!

Comment: There are a lot of strange names in any country.  I'm sorry but your question is not about English Language.

Comment: @Centaurus, Are you saying the structure of the proper names is not studied in the linguistics of the corresponding language? I think that's not the case. Ex. some languages allow proper names to be formed from the verbs, yet other from the sentences, and others from none of them. Some languages include the name of the clan or the father in the name of the child, others don't. Some proper nouns appear to be formed from colors, jobs, etc. So the syntactical and etymological questions apply to proper names just equally as their _non proper_ sisters.

Comment: Different people sometimes consider different things to be strange. Please explain what *you* find strange about the name you're asking about.

Comment: No, I'm saying that there are so many cases like this (names that sound very strange) that if we try to answer your question, we will be encouraging more of the same.

Comment: You probably *won't* enjoy this poem then...  http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~ridge/local/disobedience.html

Comment: [Born, as **John McTaggart Ellis**, in  London, 3 September1866, to Francis and Caroline Ellis. *As a condition of an inheritance* from JME's maternal grand uncle, **Sir John McTaggart**, the family took the surname '**McTaggart**.' Thus, JME became **John McTaggart Ellis McTaggart**.](http://people.stfx.ca/wsweet/mctaggart.html)

Comment: You're welcome - it's great isn't it? I suppose names from different cultures or countries will often sound strange - being composed of different syllables and being based on other contexts and environments and societies. For example the common nane 'Wiwi' in Bali does not sit well on my ears sounding too like urination for comfort. The name you mention is Scottish ie from Scotland - don't know if you know that - where it reflects I think 'clans'. Commonly names denote attachment to father via mini words like 'ben' or 'el'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._M._E._McTaggart)

> At birth, he was named John McTaggart Ellis, after his maternal grand-uncle, John McTaggart. Early in his life, his family took the surname McTaggart as a condition of inheritance from that same uncle.

So basically, they did it for the money.

Comment: So McTaggart's uncle's _full name_ formed his _first name_?

Comment: His first name was John and his family name was Ellis. They added a middlename of McTaggart to honor his (presumably rich) grand-uncle. Then as a condition of inheritance the family took McTaggart as their family name (which was, therefore, added to the end of the existing name)